# Avoid non pre-tested commit in SVN commits

Tags: java, svn

Please help me with this:
how can Avoid non pre-tested commit in SVN commits???

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but I think you should be looking at adding a CI service such as [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) into your deployment process, and enforcing a high coverage threshold through a tool like [Cobertura](http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 2):

You can't really force anybody to do anything before committing*, all you can do is test the committed code at each time.

To quote @Thomas Owens from the comments :

> Educate people who break the build on the importance of testing their code before it hits the repo.

With a particular environment you could use something like [teamcity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) which could solve your problem. But in the end anybody can commit anything on your SVN.

There are better ways to test your application. For example like

[The pre-tested commit example on teamcity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/features/continuous_integration.html#Remote_Build_Run_and_Pre-Tested_Commit)

* In fact you do, you can use the hooks of your SVN (see comments below), but in your case it would be a really bad idea.

Comment: Technically that's not true - if you wanted to you could set up an SVN hook to run the tests, and if they fail, disallow the commit. But that'd be dumb, since it'd take the duration of the tests to make a single commit.

Comment: I thought about this solution, but as you said, it's not productive at all to block the SVN at each commit waiting for the tests to be passed.

Comment: This is the point of Continuous Integration and Continuous Testing tools - run a build and test after every check in to ensure that people don't break the build. You can usually find out what check in caused the break and who made it, as well. Educate people who break the build on the importance of testing their code before it hits the repo.

Comment: I think that you should add @Rob Hruska's comment to your question - it is possible, but not benefitial in the long run (especially on larger, more complex projects).

Answer (score 0):

The most reasonable thing you can do is set up a continuous integration environment which performs a full build after each commit, and urge your team to run tests before commit.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using SVN hook scripts, like, for example post-commit, precommit, they are not the same in every operating system. But they are way useful!

Of course you should have to write your own logic combining hook scripts with some script that tells you when a code have been tested or not.

For more information look under your repository base folder, inside a folder named hooks, and you will see a whole new world!

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

For the situation where you want to commit code but you dont want to affect/break anything else one thing you can do is create a branch and commit your code to that.  After you're satisfied that its tested and is ready you can merge those commits into the truck.

Answer (score 0):

Quickest way would just to tell the ones comitting to do it by the book right? Or is that blasted human factor to much of an issue at this point for you ?

Answer (score 0):

SVN doesn't seem to be any good supported for pre-tested commits.

However, if git is also an option for you, than you may want to take a look at [Pre-tested commits with Git](http://jenkins-ci.org/content/pre-tested-commits-git) and [pre-tested commits with Hudson/Jenkins](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Designing+pre-tested+commit)